# Is there any way to reverse NSNumericSearch so NSStrings with numbers in them can be ordered in 9, 8, 7, 6... etc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ipad

I have code that returns an NSComparisonResult. My codes works great for sorting my arrays in Ascending and Descending order when they are NSStrings with only alphabetic characters in them.

When the NSStrings have numbers in them, such as `Seinfeld (Season 5)` and `Seinfeld (Season 6)` they are sorting correctly Ascending in the order of 5 and then 6. But Descending it still sorts it as 5 and 6. Here's an example:

```
Ascending:
Batman,
Seinfeld (Season 5),
Seinfeld (Season 6),
Zoolander

Descending:
Zoolander,
Seinfeld (Season 5),
Seinfeld (Season 6),
Batman
```

The descending code I have looks like this to return the comparison:

```
return [(NSString *)secondString compare:(NSString *)firstString options:NSNumericSearch];
```

Any ideas on how to reverse NSStrings with numbers in them?

By the way, I can't use NSSortDescriptor in my case. The code I have requires a custom function to be built because I have to do some string appending, etc, before the sort occurs. I didn't include it all for simplicity.

Comment: The alphanum algorithm is my favorite smart sorting algorithm, but doesn't have an objective c version (cpp though) http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Comment: @JacobJennings That's exactly what Cocoa's `NSNumericSearch` option does. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the same comment as above, but here's full source and output to prove it works (iOS 4.3 simulator tested):

```
NSArray * strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Seinfeld (Season 6)", @"Batman", @"Seinfeld (Season 5)", @"Zoolander", nil];
NSArray * sorted1 = [strings sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id first, id second) {
                        return [(NSString *)first compare:(NSString *)second options: NSNumericSearch];
                    }];
NSArray * sorted2 = [strings sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id first, id second) {
    return - [(NSString *)first compare:(NSString *)second options: NSNumericSearch];
    // or (to be more clear, but less efficient)
    // return -1 * [(NSString *)first compare:(NSString *)second options: NSNumericSearch];
}];

NSLog(@"starting: %@", strings );
NSLog(@"sort1: %@", sorted1 );
NSLog(@"sort2: %@", sorted2 );
```

output:

```
2011-10-19 02:09:07.557 test2222[16793:207] starting: (
  "Seinfeld (Season 6)",
  Batman,
  "Seinfeld (Season 5)",
  Zoolander
)

2011-10-19 02:09:07.558 test2222[16793:207] sort1: (
  Batman,
  "Seinfeld (Season 5)",
  "Seinfeld (Season 6)",
  Zoolander
)

2011-10-19 02:09:07.558 test2222[16793:207] sort2: (
  Zoolander,
  "Seinfeld (Season 6)",
  "Seinfeld (Season 5)",
  Batman
)
```

---

In answer to Ethan Allen, here's the output for a test with numbers in front:

```
2011-12-14 21:01:26.535 Test[7475:f803] starting: (
    "2001 Seinfeld (Season 6)",
    "1999 Batman",
    "2112 Seinfeld (Season 5)",
    "10 Zoolander"
)
2011-12-14 21:01:26.537 Test[7475:f803] sort1: (
    "10 Zoolander",
    "1999 Batman",
    "2001 Seinfeld (Season 6)",
    "2112 Seinfeld (Season 5)"
)
2011-12-14 21:01:26.537 Test[7475:f803] sort2: (
    "2112 Seinfeld (Season 5)",
    "2001 Seinfeld (Season 6)",
    "1999 Batman",
    "10 Zoolander"
)
```

Comment: Now what is the items have number in front of them? Like "12 Monkeys", "2001 A Space Odyssey", "300", "3D Movie", "1900 was a great year". Will these be sorted in numerical order correctly?

Comment: @EthanAllen - pretty easy to test since I pasted all the code directly above :)  New Project, paste this into application delegate app did finish launching method and you'll know the answer.  Writing test programs is a key developer skill.  Took me less than 2 minutes to copy the code above, create a New Empty iOS application, paste the code into the app delegate did finish launching method, modify the strings to put numbers in front and run it.  Answer added to the above.

Answer (score 1):

Just return -(NSComparisonResult)

Comment: Return the negative of the current compare:

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Batman",
              @"Seinfeld (Season 5)",
              @"Seinfeld (Season 6)",
              @"Zoolander", nil];
```

//for ascending

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id firstString, id secondString) {
  return [(NSString *)firstString compare:(NSString *)secondString  options:NSNumericSearch];
}];

  NSLog(@"========= %@================= ", sortedArray);
```

//for descending

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id firstString, id secondString) {
  return [(NSString *)secondString compare:(NSString *)firstString  options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: I don't get it... your ascending and descending code is exactly the same.

Comment: hey Ethan, in descending method try using this code:  return [(NSString *)secondString compare:(NSString *)firstString  options:NSNumericSearch];

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Benjamin Mayo's answer:

Let's say your "ascending" comparison function is this:

```
static NSComparisonResult compareAscending(id s1, id s2, void *context) {
    return [s1 compare:s2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

Then this should be your "descending" comparison function:

```
static NSComparisonResult compareDescending(id s1, id s2, void *context) {
    return -compareAscending(s1, s2, context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I know it may be painful however I believe it would be useful for you in the long run. I recommend writing your own sorting function and here what I would do. You might need two functions but this way you can tweak them to be exactly what you want. 
In order to sort them I recommend looking at each characters ascii value and adding them all together and then comparing them against anothers ascii value all together and if descending return the lower one if ascending return the higher one. As for the sorting algorithm part You could use an bubble sort. That is the easiest however it is slow so if this is something that needs to be quick then I would recommend taking time to look at a mergesort. Anyways hope this helps. If you need help righting a sorting method ide love to help you, it looks like you are a pretty good coder though:)